Overriding Default Link Text Color within Custom Template
I have the following custom template within Oracle APEX, it is a near identical copy of the media list report template:


<li class="t-MediaList-item #LIST_CLASS#">
  <a href="#LINK#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;" class="t-MediaList-itemWrap #LINK_CLASS#" #LINK_ATTR#>
    <div class="t-MediaList-iconWrap" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="t-MediaList-icon u-color #ICON_COLOR_CLASS#"><span class="t-Icon #ICON_CLASS#"></span>       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="t-MediaList-body">
      <h3 class="t-MediaList-title">#LIST_TITLE#</h3>
      <p class="t-MediaList-desc">#LIST_TEXT#</p>
    </div>
    <div class="t-Badge-badgeWrap">
      #LIST_BADGE#
    </div>
  </a>
</li>



I am trying to override the blue color that the link text defaults to and am having no luck so far.  I have tried adding !important tags to both text-decoration: none; and color: inherit; and that didn't help me either.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

It could be that links have events as well such as link.active , link.hover, etc.  What code are you using ?  As in a link unclicked, a link thats been clicked, a link that is being hovered will all be a different color usually.   A previously visited sometimes is purple, etc.   If you do style="color:red !Important;'  does that work ?

Changing the color to red did not work, and I am using HTML

so you have 2 classes pointing to this : t-MediaList-itemWrap #LINK_CLASS#, is the LINK-ATTR# suppose to be in there too? Its on the end by its self.  But I would look at the CSS for those classes and see if they are forcing some things.  Oh just saw your close  tag .. with all that going into the link, perhaps it would function more properly using a  tags instead, as they are easier to style.

If you're on apex 22.1 or higher, this can be solved using css variables, see this related question.

Step 1: identify the behaviour of the element by inspecting it. (In google chrome) right click the link and look at it's attributes:



Click on "--ut-medialist-title-text-color" to see how it is defined



Now that you have the name of the css variable... change it in page attributes > inline css (or in your custom css file)



result:


